# Wordpress next previous post

Tags: php, wordpress

code is not running. the name does not appear. I looked at all the sites but couldn't find anything

```
<?php 
$prev_post  = get_previous_post();
$prev_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->post_title));
$prev_ID    = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $prev_post->ID));
$prev       = previous_posts_link($prev_ID);
$prevlink   = get_permalink($prev_ID);
?>

<div class="previuos">
    <a href="<?php echo $prevlink ?>"> <?php print_r($prev_post->post_title) ?></a>
</div>
<?php
$next_post  = get_next_post();
$next_title = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->post_title));

$next_id    = strip_tags(str_replace('"', '', $next_post->ID));
$next       = next_posts_link($next_id);
$nextlink   = get_permalink($next_id);
?>
<div class="next">
    <a href="<?php echo $nextlink ?>"> <?php echo $next_title; ?></a>
</div>
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking here.

Comment: Please clarify which sites you used and what you already tried, so other people know which solutions are not working for you. Seeing you use the words 'next' and 'previous', do you mean you have trouble with the value of a navigation link? Which name do you want to appear and where? Updating your question with this information will help others to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a difference in both lines with an `<a>`-tag, because in the first one you write `print_r($prev_post->post_title)`, but the second one has `echo $next_title`. You might want to try `echo` for both values, so your code becomes:

```
<a href="<?php echo $prevlink ?>"> <?php echo($prev_title); ?></a>
```

The method `print_r()` is better suited when you want to print output for an array, so `echo` is probably what you need here, because you expect text, not an array.

If that is not working, please provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) because we might use other input than you are using.